# Find multiple duplicate rows in SQL Server table by name and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2019

I am trying to find duplicate records by name and the date submitted.

For example, I want to get all records with same name of "SampleOne" and same submitted date of "2016-10-14 12:44 39 460" and exclude any data that doesn't match.

I am using the query shown below, but I'm getting other data too. From my screenshot below I need only rows 1- 4 and not show the ones that doesn't have the same name and same `submitDate`.

```
SELECT TOP (13) 
    a.DocumentName, a.SubmitDateTime
FROM 
    Document AS a 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  
         DocumentName, SubmitDateTime, COUNT(*) AS DocCount
     FROM    
         Document
     GROUP BY 
         DocumentName, SubmitDateTime
     HAVING  
         (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS dt ON a.DocumentName = dt.DocumentName 
                               AND a.SubmitDateTime = dt.SubmitDateTime 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Staging b ON a.DocumentId = b.DocumentId
WHERE 
    b.DocumentId IS NULL  
    AND a.SubmitDateTime IS NOT NULL
    AND a.InsertDateTime IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    a.SubmitDateTime
```

Sample data

| DocumentName | SubmitDateTime |
| --- | --- |
| SampleOne | 2016-10-14 12:44:39.460 |
| SampleOne | 2016-10-14 12:44:39.460 |
| SampleTwo | 2016-10-14 12:44:39.460 |
| SampleTwo | 2016-10-14 12:44:39.460 |
| SampleThree | 2016-10-14 12:45:32.813 |
| SampleFive | 2016-10-14 12:46:23.423 |
| Doc Name | 2016-10-17 15:15:05.523 |
| Doc Name 2 | 2016-10-17 15:15:32.170 |
| Doc Name | 2016-10-17 15:17:32.153 |
| Doc Name | 2016-10-17 15:17:53.963 |
| Doc Name | 2016-10-17 15:18:15.977 |
| Document Text | 2016-10-17 15:19:22.950 |
| Document Text | 2016-10-17 15:22:25.463 |

I have managed to get the results that I want by using the query below and needs suggestion if I am on the right track.

```
   SELECT    t.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        s.*
      , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.DocumentName, s.SubmitDateTime, s.DocumentType) AS DocCount
    FROM Document s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Staging b ON S.DocumentId = b.DocumentId
     WHERE 
     b.DocumentId IS NULL 
     AND s.SubmitDateTime IS NOT NULL
     AND s.InsertDateTime IS NOT NULL
     AND s.DocumentName IS NOT NULL
    ) t
    
WHERE t.DocCount> 1
  
ORDER BY t.DocumentName, t.SubmitDateTime
```

Comment: Window functions can give you what you need.

Comment: Sample data and expected results, as text not images would help immensely

Comment: As already mentioned, please post your sample data as text. I for one can't see it as imgur is blocked on my corporate network

Comment: Added sample data as text

Comment: And expected results...

Comment: Does "same submitted date" mean you want matching dates or date/times? A day is many milliseconds.

Comment: I expect to see  SampleOne and SampleTwo only

Comment: I also expect to see the date/times as it appears in my sample date. Example 2016-10-14 12:44:39.460 for SampleOne

Comment: I am matching the date/times but if the date only will give me the expected output, I will like that too. Because from my sample data, I want to see only  4 rows with SampleOne and SampleTwo

Comment: I have managed to get the results that I want and needs suggestions if it is good

Comment: SELECT    t.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        s.*
      , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.DocumentName, s.SubmitDateTime, s.DocumentType) AS DocCount
    FROM Document s
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Staging b ON S.DocumentId = b.DocumentId
  WHERE 
  b.DocumentId IS NULL 
     AND s.SubmitDateTime IS NOT NULL
     AND s.InsertDateTime IS NOT NULL
  AND s.DocumentName IS NOT NULL
    ) t
 
WHERE t.DocCount> 1
  
ORDER BY t.DocumentName, t.SubmitDateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any clear input or output I am assuming the following:

The subquery `t` will select only the necessary columns `DocumentName` and `SubmitDateTime`.

I replaced the`LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `Staging` with a `LEFT JOIN` for simplicity, assuming you don't require columns from the `Staging` table in the final result.
In the `COUNT(*)` function I included the OVER PARTITION to count duplicates only based on `DocumentName` and `SubmitDateTime`.

```sql
SELECT t.DocumentName, t.SubmitDateTime
FROM (
    SELECT s.DocumentName, s.SubmitDateTime, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.DocumentName, s.SubmitDateTime) AS DocCount
    FROM Document s
    LEFT JOIN Staging b ON s.DocumentId = b.DocumentId
    WHERE b.DocumentId IS NULL
        AND s.SubmitDateTime IS NOT NULL
        AND s.InsertDateTime IS NOT NULL
        AND s.DocumentName IS NOT NULL
) t
WHERE t.DocCount > 1
ORDER BY t.DocumentName, t.SubmitDateTime;
```